# Advantages of library

Tags: java

I have one java file with numbers of functions around 30-40 that I use commonly, so I am thinking to make external library of it.

But I want to know **what are the advantages of making library except it does not need to import like java file**, is there any performance advantage of making library?

Comment: What do you mean by "making library"? Putting the class(es) into a jar-file?

Comment: _except it does not need to import_ Every external library **need to be imported.**

Comment: @BackSlash: unless it's in the same package

Comment: @nneonneo How can it be in the same package if it's _external_?

Comment: @BackSlash: two completely separate classes can use the same `package` declaration, and they don't need to `import` each other (but they do have to both be on the classpath).

Comment: none whatsoever. there is no difference between including java files, class files or jar files (unless you use optimization processes such as method inlining, in which case, including java files is more efficient. It makes sense, too : the compiler has all the info to make the optimization.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Libraries and frameworks have these advantages:

1. Reduce the size of your class files (code can be extracted and moved elsewhere where it don't disturb anyone).
2. Cleaner API since you can't leak internal fields
3. You can test your library independent of your application. If the library is good, then the bug must be in your app. Reduces test and debug time.
4. You can reuse a library in several projects.

Comment: Great answer.  Just to add (since @commit was interested), there aren't really performance benefits _per se_ in moving it to an external library.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a library if the API is mature enough, and robust enough.
If you always need to edit it, You may just lose you time in maintenance.
One advantage: it forces you to take care of the API.